# Parsing an entire text file in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to read a text file for usernames and passwords for a final project. I can get the scanner to read one line, but only one line. I also need to be able to pass the username information along to print a file base on a role contained in the credentials file. Currently, it will only validate the line by line. If I enter the username and password correctly from the first line of the credentials file, it works as expected. If I enter it incorrectly, it will only accept the username and password from the second line of the credentials file.

My question is how do I parse the credentials file properly to search the entire file, not just an individual line.

I do not need to worry about the hash, only the password which is in parenthesis. I also must then print another text file which references the fourth item in each line, but I haven't gotten that far yet.. Any help would be most appreciated.

Text File:

```
griffin.keyes   108de81c31bf9c622f76876b74e9285f    "alphabet soup" zookeeper
rosario.dawson  3e34baa4ee2ff767af8c120a496742b5    "animal doctor" admin
bernie.gorilla  a584efafa8f9ea7fe5cf18442f32b07b    "secret password"    veterinarian
donald.monkey   17b1b7d8a706696ed220bc414f729ad3    "M0nk3y business"   zookeeper
jerome.grizzlybear  3adea92111e6307f8f2aae4721e77900    "grizzly1234"   veterinarian
bruce.grizzlybear   0d107d09f5bbe40cade3de5c71e9e9b7    "letmein"   admin
```

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException  {
File file = new File ("C:\\Users\\Rick\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\IT145finalproject4\\src\\it145finalproject4\\credentials.txt");

    String passWord;
    String userName;
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner (file);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);



    while(scnr.hasNextLine()){
        int attempts = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        String line = scnr.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter a username:" );
        userName = sc.nextLine();            
        System.out.println("Enter a password:");  
        passWord = sc.nextLine();


            if(line.contains(userName) && (line.contains (passWord))){
              return;                
            }

            if (!line.contains(userName) && (!line.contains (passWord))){
                System.out.println("Please try again.");
            }

            attempts++;
            if (attempts == 3){
                System.out.println("Maximum attempts reached program exiting.");
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [ask]. Describe your question concretely, include what you've tried as code, not an offsite screenshot, etc.

Comment: I think you exit the while loop when you check if the line has `userName` and `passWord`.

Comment: Also, can you post your code (via copy/paste instead of an image)

Comment: Sorry was rushing to get it posted. I've been working on this all day and am getting nowhere.

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: I edited my post again to reflect my question. I'm sorry, but I'm really frustrated with project.

Comment: Try writing out on paper first, then translate to code. The logical flow should look something like this: `3 times: { read credentials, load file [consider caching], for each line: if one matches, return success } return failure`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this amendment fixes the issues you were describing:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestClass
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  
{
    File file = new File ("C:\\Users\\Mel\\Documents\\test.txt");

    String passWord = "";
    String userName = "";
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner (file);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    int attempts = 0, numLines = 0, count = 0;

    //Get the number of lines in the file
    while(scnr.hasNext())
    {
        numLines++;
        scnr.nextLine();
    }

    //Reset the scanner
    scnr.close();
    scnr = new Scanner(file);

    while(scnr.hasNextLine())
    {
        count++;
        String line = scnr.nextLine();

        //only run this code once per file iteration (at the start)
        if (count == 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a username:" );
            userName = sc.nextLine();            
            System.out.println("Enter a password:");  
            passWord = sc.nextLine();
        }

        if(line.contains(userName) && (line.contains (passWord))){
            return; //success!               
        }

        //only execute this code once the entire file has been scanned!
        if (count == numLines)
        {
            attempts++;
            if (attempts == 3){
                System.out.println("Maximum attempts reached program exiting.");
                return;
            } 
            if (!line.contains(userName) || (!line.contains (passWord))){
                System.out.println("Please try again.");
                //reset scanner!
                scnr.close();
                scnr = new Scanner(file);
                count = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best solution but I think it is an improvement. Mainly your issue was in not resetting the scanner, but also in calling the input methods too frequently. You will see that the number of lines are initially calculated to help determine when certain code should be called.

I also removed the for loop as it appeared to have no bearing on the code.